# How do I duplicate values in R?

Tags: r, vector

Assume I have the following vector:

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

If I wanted to expand this vector so that there are 50 1 values, 50 2 values, etc., how would I do this?
Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
rep(v1, 2)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

Or with each (after @Rui's comment):

```
rep(v1, each = 2)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

Comment: Or argument `each = 2`.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas I have expanded my answer.